# Onmouseover on echo img

Tags: php, html

I try to call alert function with the onmouseover event on an image.

In pure HTML5 it works. But in PHP it doesn't. How is it possible to bypass this?

```
<?php
        echo "<img onmouseover="alert('hello world')" src="http://www.seniorennet.be/Images/Huisdieren/Muizen/muis.jpg"></img>";
?>
```

Comment: When you start your echo with double quotes you have to either escape them when you use them again inside the echo or use single quotes. The reason is, that when you start with double quotes, you also stop when you use double quotes again. So it's trying to use `alert` like a phpfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be escaping your quotes like this:

```
echo "<img onmouseover=\"alert('hello world')\" src=\"http://www.seniorennet.be/Images/Huisdieren/Muizen/muis.jpg\"></img>";
```

or like this:

```
echo '<img onmouseover="alert(\'hello world\')" src="http://www.seniorennet.be/Images/Huisdieren/Muizen/muis.jpg"></img>';
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2661520/1400370) for more info on why we escape quotes/characters

Comment: Not quite sure what the downvote was for, if I've missed anything, let me know and I'll correct the post.